# ngTable basic example not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

https://plnkr.co/edit/z7I2zewXwvovZ8023rHm?p=preview

Please help me with this ngTable example in the above plnkr. I m not able to display table and when i see the console log there is error of single element for template.

code:
script.js

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"]);
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,NgTableParams){
var self = this;
var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name:"Moroni", age: 50}];
self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { data: data});
});
```

index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp" controller="myCtrl as vm">
{{8+7}}
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
      <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
        {{user.name}}</td>
      <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
        {{user.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order you reference the scripts are wrong, script.js should load after loading the ng-table

```
<div class="container">
    <table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
                {{user.name}}</td>
            <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
                {{user.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ob9M8SPpzujESsWWweL6?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0" data-semver="1.2.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/1.0.0/dist/ng-table.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/1.0.0/dist/ng-table.js"></script>
  <script>
  // Code goes here

angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,NgTableParams){
  var self = this;
  var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name: "Moroni", age: 50},{name: "Moroni", age: 50}];
self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: data});
});
  </script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    {{8+7}}
    <table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
          <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
            {{user.name}}</td>
          <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
            {{user.age}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```